# Cannot load the Css

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a folder in content like this

```
-Content
--jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom
--------------------------css
--------------------------smoothness
------------------------------------jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css
------------------------------------jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css
--------------------------js
--------------------------jquery-1.10.2.js
--------------------------jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js
--------------------------jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js
```

in  `BundleConfig.cs` I added

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness").Include(
                "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css",
                "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"
        ));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js").Include(
                "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js",
                "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js",
                "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"
```

));

and finally in code am trying to do something like

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js")
}

<h2 class="demoHeaders">Tabs</h2>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis, sollicitudin eu, felis. Pellentesque nisi urna, interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus. Mauris porttitor ullamcorper augue.</div>
</div>
```

but I cannot see the style effect , any idea what's wrong in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things you are doing wrong:

First, if you are using bundling (and minification), there is no need to include `*.min.*` versions of the files in your bundles. Just skip those.

Second, in your view you are not actually rendering the bundles - the names are wrong. You should use the bundle names you set in your `BundleConfig`. Also, you don't need to put calls to `.Render()` inside `@{ ... }` block. Try this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness")
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js")
```

For readability, I suggest to name your bundles something like `~/Content/styles` and `~/Content/scripts`. Also, normally you'd render them in your `_Layout.cshtml` not in any particular view, unless those bundles apply only to that view.